# Firefox 2 freezes when trying cross-browser inline-block trick

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox2

I am trying to design a form that uses the CSS inline-block display value for a table-like arrangement. I know that some browsers including Firefox 2 don't know how to handle it, so I used this method to make it work in all browsers. However, sometimes when I try it in Firefox 2, the browser freezes. My CPU usage gets stuck near 100% and sometimes the memory usage rapidly increases to a huge value. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to work around it? Here is a simple example of a page that shows this problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>-moz-inline-stack test</title>
<style type="text/css">
div {
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="yes">
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="no">
</div>
</body></html>
```

It works fine in Firefox 3 but it freezes Firefox 2. The <br> tag is not necessary for the bug but it keeps the inputs from being on top of each other.

Comment: I have decided to give up on this question. I tried Andy Ford's suggestion, and it kept the browser from crashing, but it caused other visual quirks. Eventually, I got my site to work in Firefox 2. It doesn't look quite the same, but I figured that so few people still use Firefox 2 that it is not worth it for me to try to diagnose this. If anyone cares, someone else will have to handle this question.

Comment: This may be kind of late, but in case anyone is interested, here is where I learned about the trick:
http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Answer (score 2):

try this instead

```
div {
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```